# How to ignore LogDebug when LogLevel set to Information

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, logging, serilog

I'm using ASP.NET Core with Serilog.

In controller I have some logs for debug like:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Get(...)
{
    _logger.LogInformation("Action Get is running");
    _logger.LogDebug("-- debug log. deserialized payload: {Payload}", DeserializePayload(message));
    ...
}
```

and method

```
private string DeserializePayload(byte[] message)
{
    _logger.LogInformation("DeserializePayload is running");
    ...
    return "json as a string";
}
```

`MinimumLevel` is set to `Information`!

How to ignore calling of `DeserializePayload` in debug log when minimum level is set to `Information`? 
Result will be

> Action Get is running
>
> DeserializePayload is running

I need to skip running of DeserializePayload method when I don't need debug log. Is there any way how to do it except using `#if DEBUG`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can ask Serilog if the `Debug` event log level is enabled, and then decide if you should call your `DeserializePayload` method.

e.g.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Get(...)
{
    _logger.LogInformation("Action Get is running");

    if (_logger.IsEnabled(LogLevel.Debug))
    {
        _logger.LogDebug("-- debug log. deserialized payload: {Payload}", DeserializePayload(message));
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: thanks. I think, I can do this check in some extension method and use it everywhere, right?

Comment: @Chebur You sure can... Just create an extension method that targets `ILogger`

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the way the logger works is that the `_logger.LogDebug` always runs, but the level suppresses outputting to your log source (implemented by the logger). Here you need conditional logic to check the log level first (i'm assuming running `DeserializePayload` is an expensive operation you are trying to avoid). So you need some level of conditional logic based on the configured log level. Based solely on your snippet and not having any other view into how your application is structured, I would suggest injecting `IConfiguration` into this class and use it to check the configured logging level.

Comment: so i guess this is also true for other logs as in log information also always run